# LinkedIn API Field Projections on array

Tags: linkedin-api, projection, response-headers

Newer version of LinkedIn API endpoints are using **Field Projections** ([Field Projection link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/api-guide/concepts/projections?context=linkedin%2Fcontext)) for customizing response. How can I use this for response which by default is returning array?

For example, how can I do the same as described in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/compliance/integrations/organizations/organization-access-control?tabs=http#using-projections) with using **Field Projections**?